# How bad is this dent?

Tags: guitar

Today, I was cleaning my room, and I put a phone powerbank on a bed. I wanted to put guitar close to it, but when I stood near the bed, I blacked out (for a few secs) and accidentally dropped my guitar onto this powerbank. It fell on the sharp edge and left this dent on the back side of the body. How bad is this dent and how is it fixable (well, at least so it won’t noticeable right off the bat). I left photos below.

Update:
My phone camera sucks and it can't make good macro (gets very blurry when getting close to the object).

#### Describing this dent will sound like this:

It looks like a half of a circle (I'm bad at English maths, so I'll refer to the top enclosing line as circle diameter, and to the half itself as arc), where the circle diameter (the straight line) is on the same level as other parts with varnish, so you can say, that the top border is on the baseline. The arc (starting from the contour) is pressed inside by less than 2 millimeters. So the circle diameter is now overlaying the continuation of arc which stretches inside (below it) by 1 mm (or so). Varnish is still in place – no cracks.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You should get checked out ASAP for the black out. For the dent, it’s not clear what you mean by “how bad”. It’s exactly as bad as it is?

Comment: GO TO A DOCTOR.  NOW.  Once you get back from the doctor, you need to give us a bit more information - what kind of guitar, exactly how big/deep the dent is (need something in the picture for scale).  IME, dents are mostly a cosmetic issue and don't affect tone, but I play cheap guitars.

Comment: Both the pictures are quite out of focus - if you're taking them on a phone, see if you can get it to actually focus on the dent.

Comment: Came to make the same comment. Passing out is way more concerning than the dent. Guitar should be fine even with a dent. Get your head checked. I hope you’re ok.

Comment: Were you tired at the time? It's possible that you're using the term "blacked out" to mean something far less serious such as dozing off.

Comment: How do dents get classified? On a score of 1 to 10? Surely the ramifications of a dent are far more important than the dent itself? The pics are inconclusive, but using guesswork, they seem to be non-life-threatening. Which is way less important than finding the causes of your 'blackout'. Which obviously is beyond the remit of this site. Get yourself checked out before you worry about a dented guitar.

Comment: Asking from ignorance - is this an acoustic or a solidbody electric?  What's the material?  Dented wood doesn't matter, but a related crack would matter.  Dented metal/plastic/fiberglass doesn't matter at all.  You should see what  brass sousaphones look like after a few years of (mis)use.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft It's a Fender Stratocaster, so it's solidbody electric. Body is alder.

Comment: @EugenEray: You may want to make sure that the shock from the impact didn't also break a solder joint on the switch or pots, or affect the neck alignment.  I'd be surprised if it did, but can't hurt to check.  Apart from that, it's cosmetic issue and shouldn't affect playability or tone.  And what did the doctor say?

Comment: @JohnBode Thanks for the answer. It was a sudden pressure drop (both blood and arterial) because of lack of oxygen in the room. So it was very hot that day and I locked all the windows to prevent outdoors noise (car noise, bird singing etc), plus I was wearing pretty warm clothes (as for this season). It wasn't anything too bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually a dent or a scratch won't really affect the ability of the instrument to make music, but some folks are real persnickety about the way their instrument looks. In that case find a good luthier and let him fix it like new for you. Some of them can work wonders!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I updated the info, maybe you could say something about the dent more detailed based on description, because my camera can't do macro.

Comment: @Eugen Eray- sometimes wood that has been compressed in this fashion can be restored by applying steam which will make the wood swell back to it"s original shape, but I would expect the finish on the dent would need to be removed to allow moisture to penetrate the wood effectively. After the dent is removed, new finish will need to be applied to the repair.  I'd probably recommend having a luthier take care of this.